# MySQL Root User

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I was trying to create a very simple MySQL event and realized the action was not running. I then realized that the user I was using did not have super privileges (or any other event-related privileges). I tried granting all privileges to this user via phpMyAdmin but that wasn't working (makes since because I was logged in as that user and not the root user). In fact, I'm not sure if my account has a root user. **How do I find out who the root user is (username and password)?**

I'm using a hosting provider that has cpanel and when I look at a list of my mysql users I only see the ones I created. **Is there a way I can find out via phpMyAdmin if I'm logged in as another user?**

Also, whenever I create a user in cpanel, I always select the checkbox to grant "all privileges" but I found out just now that super priviledge and a few other privileges are not on the list. As far as I can tell, I won't be able to create any mysql events since I can't grant super privileges to any of my users.

**Addition:**

When assigning a user to a database, the only privileges I can select from are

- ALTER
- ALTER ROUTINE
- CREATE
- CREATE ROUTINE
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
- CREATE VIEW
- DELETE
- DROP
- EXECUTE
- INDEX
- INSERT
- LOCK TABLES
- REFERENCES
- SELECT
- SHOW VIEW
- TRIGGER
- UPDATE

From what everyone is saying in their answers it looks like I'm using a shared database, the event schedule is either turned off and/or I am not allowed to grant users privileges dealing with events. Kind of sucks..

But for now I will use cron jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule of thumb: **Your application never, ever needs superuser privileges.**

Not even to use the event system.

The only thing you need SUPER for in this instance is to enable or disable the scheduler (which is a server-wide setting). If you're on a shared database host, it will be up to the provider whether or not the scheduler is enabled, and whether you've been granted the EVENT privilege on your database(s).

If you're not on a shared host, check your my.ini for the **[event-scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler)** line and make sure it's enabled. Then, make sure you've **[granted EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-privileges.html)** to your application userid. The EVENT privilege should be granted if you've used `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` on the database (as opposed to on individual tables).

Comment: I was trying to enable the scheduler setting but was unable to, probably because I am on a shared db server but I'm not sure. (Pretty certain though now that you have explained it). But I will check my php.ini file as well.

Comment: But you do need privileges to define functions, so you WILL need them in development.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to contact your hosting provider and ask for event-related privileges for your account. They most likely store all their user databases under the same MySQL server, so for obvious security reasons root access can't be granted.

Answer (score 0):

`select user()` would tell you the login that the query's executing under.

However, you should NOT grant 'super user' privileges to any code that handles DB operations for public-facing code. For proper security, public-facing DB code SHOULD have the minimum privileges required to get the job done. Usually that would update/insert/delete/select only.

Granting things like drop/alter/create/grant/etc... is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I'm able to drop and alter. I cannot grant.

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to create a very simple MySQL event and realized the action was not running. I then realized that the user I was using did not have super privileges

While reading this you might first implement better checking and handling for exceptions since this should release some error in your system for sure. This is a complex task requiring extensive handling of errors to see whether this goes right otherwise you will likely find yourself searching for a bug in this part for hours.